# Mercurial & TortoiseHg - args error to config a diff tool?

Tags: mercurial, config, tortoisehg, args, difftool

*I'm trying to configure a diff tool in TortoiseHg and Mercurial.*

*This is the configuratión I've done:*

```
[merge-tools]
CmpIt.executable = E:\Program Files (x86)\Compare It!\wincmp3.exe
CmpIt.priority = 1
CmpIt.premerge = True
CmpIt.gui = True

CmpIt.args= -m $local $base $other
CmpIt.diffargs= -m $local $base
CmpIt.dirdiff= True
```

*But when the tool start, it's looking for "**$local**" and "**$base**" files instead real file names.*

*I found on Task Manager that the command line is geting the names of the args instead their values:*

```
E:\Program Files (x86)\Compare It!\wincmp3.exe -m $local $base
```

*How can I force to pass the value of the args to the command line?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss some **important** points

1. You must to avoid usage CompareIt! as merge-tool (it still doesn't support 3-way merge): `CmpIt.args` is BIG NO-NO for now
2. You have to re-read `hgrc.d\MergeTools.rc` (of any merge-tool part) for parameters, used in .diffargs, parred by TortoiseHG/Mercurial: `$local` + `$base` are variables *for merge, not for diff*
3. You have to re-read [CompareIt! command-line options](http://www.grigsoft.com/wincmp3/help/source/html/cmp_commandlineusage.htm): they doesn't mention `-m` at all

From my POV, using bcompare.diffargs options as quick-start and CompareIT! Help for "translation", this will reasonably good first iteration (not tested!!!)

<strike>`CmpIt.args= -m $local $base $other`</strike>

`CmpIt.diffargs= $parent /=$plabel1 $child /=$clabel`